# Is it possible to add custom functions on Laravel Models?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have an Orders table that has relations to a Movements table, and im constantly doing things like this to calculate several common values for each order:

```
$warehouse = 7;
$order = Order::find(16111);
$entries = Movement::selectRaw("SUM(gross) AS total_gross")
    ->selectRaw("SUM(net) AS total_net")
    ->selectRaw("SUM(qty) AS total_qty")
    ->where('order_id', $order->id)
    ->where('to_id', $warehouse)
    ->first();
$exits = Movement::selectRaw("SUM(gross) AS total_gross")
    ->selectRaw("SUM(net) AS total_net")
    ->selectRaw("SUM(qty) AS total_qty")
    ->where('order_id', $order->id)
    ->where('from_id', $warehouse)
    ->first();
```

is it possible to create a custom function to just query the DB doing something like this:

```
$warehouse = 7;
$entries = Order::find(16111)->entries($warehouse);
$exits = Order::find(16111)->exits($warehouse);
```

If so how can it be done?

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Models are just classes that inherit some database methods. You can put whatever functions you want in them. `public function entries() {...`.

Comment: You'd get your `id` by doing `$this->id` since you're within the class, and get the warehouse passed into the function. The rest of your code would remain the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely. What you are looking for is called [local Query Scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes); it allows you to avoid repeating complexe queries in your code.

> Local scopes allow you to define common sets of query constraints that you may easily re-use throughout your application.

Write your local query scope in your model and you'll never have to repeat this code again (DRY principle).

---

Here's an example to give you an idea, you'll need to tweak it to your needs.

**In your Order model:**

```
public function scopeEntries($query)
{
    $warehouse = $this->warehouse; // Take advantage of Eloquent wherever you can

    return $query->movements()->selectRaw("SUM(gross) AS total_gross")
        ->selectRaw("SUM(net) AS total_net")
        ->selectRaw("SUM(qty) AS total_qty")
        ->where('to_id', $warehouse->id);
}

public function scopeExits($query)
{
    $warehouse = $this->warehouse; // Take advantage of Eloquent wherever you can

    return $query->movements()->selectRaw("SUM(gross) AS total_gross")
        ->selectRaw("SUM(net) AS total_net")
        ->selectRaw("SUM(qty) AS total_qty")
        ->where('from_id', $warehouse->id)
        ->where('to_id', $warehouse->id);
}
```

Now in your code, you will be able to simply call `$order->entries()->first()` to retrieve the first entry but you can also call `$order->exits()->get()` to retrieve all exits.

Comment: Totally agree with @LobsterBaz, this is the way to do it. However, I have always had trouble with refactoring and autocompletion when using them. Especially if you use the same name over multiple models. i try to name the functions in each model, so they are unique and easy to find with a plaintext search, eg scopeWarehouseExits or scopeWarehoueEntries, but in the end it really comes down to how many models have the same funtionality